# парсинг тайтлов slashlib в которых есть возрастное ограничение python

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Всё никак не пойму чего не хватает слэшлибу, что бы он выводил данные по всем тайтлам в том числе по 18+

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#

# Список User-Agent строк

url = r'https://v1.slashlib.me/team/dead-inside-team'
s = requests.Session()
s.get(url)
xsrf = s.cookies['XSRF-TOKEN']

r = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
csrf = soup.find('meta', {'name': '_token'})['content']

print (csrf)
print (xsrf)
    # Заголовки запроса
headers = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf,
    'X-XSRF-TOKEN': xsrf

}
links = []  # Создаем пустой список для хранения ссылок
links2 = []
# Отправляем GET-запрос к странице с заголовками
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
# Проверяем успешность запроса
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Используем BeautifulSoup для парсинга HTML-кода страницы
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Находим все элементы с тегом заголовка новости
    for link in soup.find_all('a', class_='media-card'):
        print(link)
        pars = link.get('href')
        pars2 = link.get('data-src')
        links.append(pars)  # Добавляем ссылку в список
        links2.append(pars2)
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_headers() -> dict:
    """Генерируем `headers` с токенами."""
    with requests.Session() as session:
        session.get("https://v1.slashlib.me/")
        cookies = session.cookies.get_dict()
        
    xsrf_token = cookies["XSRF-TOKEN"].replace("%3D", "=")
    mangalib_session = cookies["mangalib_session"].replace("%3D", "=")
    cookie = f"XSRF-TOKEN={xsrf_token}; mangalib_session={mangalib_session}"
    
    return {"X-XSRF-TOKEN": xsrf_token, "Cookie": cookie}


def get_url_soup(url: str) -> BeautifulSoup:
    """Получем `soup` из ссылки для `BeautifulSoup`."""
    with requests.Session() as session:
        response = session.get(url, headers=get_headers())
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")


def get_manga_from_soup(soup: BeautifulSoup) -> list[dict]:
    """Получеам все тайтлы из ссылки на команду."""
    media_list = soup.select("a.media-card")
    manga_list = [
        {
            "title": media.select_one("h3.media-card__title").getText(strip=True),
            "cover": media.get("data-src"),
            "href": media.get("href")
        } 
        for media in media_list
    ]
    return manga_list
        

def main() -> None:
    url = "https://v1.slashlib.me/team/blchk"
    
    soup = get_url_soup(url)
    manga_list = get_manga_from_soup(soup)
    
    print(manga_list)
    
    """Сохраняем результат в JSON файл.
    import json
    
    filename = "manga.json"
    with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        json.dump(manga_list, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
    """
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```